# Is there a way to cycle through divs and get the div that was clicked to add a class?

Tags: reactjs

I have five divs that I want to have an active class when clicked. I already have an active class in my css, but I don't know how I would add that in my code

```
import React from 'react';
import './filter.scss';


const Filter = (props) => {



    return (
        <div className="filter">
            <div className="filter__alle active">
                <p>Alle</p> <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div className="filter__eiendom ">
                <p>Eiendom</p> <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div className="filter__familie ">
                <p>Familie</p> <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div className="filter__kontrakt">
                <p>Kontrakt</p> <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div className="filter__husarbeid ">
                <p>Husarbeid</p> <span>2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Filter;
```

Comment: Only one item from the list can be active? (if I clicked not an active item, should active item deactivate?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better way save active div index in the state:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { name: "Alle", text: 2 },
  { name: "Eiendom", text: 2 },
  { name: "Familie", text: 2 },
  { name: "Kontrakt", text: 2 },
  { name: "Husarbeid", text: 2 }
];

const Filter = props => {
  const [activIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState(null);
  const handleClick = index => {
    console.log(index);
    setActiveIndex(index);
  };
  return (
    <div className="filter">
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={
            activIndex === index ? "filter__item active" : "filter__item"
          }
          onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
        >
          <p>{item.name}</p> <span>{item.text}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add active class like this

```
import styles from './filter.scss';

<div className={`${styles.active} filter__alle active`}>
                <p>Alle</p> <span>2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think OP wants to map data through an object and set different click handlers for each of them. For that case, you can just toggle the class attribute of the current target element. Refers to my code,

```js
const Filter = (props) => {
    const list = ["Alle", "Eiendom", "Familie", "Kontrakt", "Husarbeid"]
    const handleClick = e => {
         e.target.classList.toggle("active");
    }

    return (
        <div className="filter">
        {list.map(name => (
            <div className="filter__alle" key={name} onClick={handleClick}>
                <p>{name}</p> <span>2</span>
            </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```